# How can i change the color of d3.js radar chart in dependence of values

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, charts

I created a survey on my html website. A radar chart is displayed as a result. All answers are assigned to parent groups. Then I calculate which group has the highest sum of all values. I would like to display the lines of the radar chart in different colors depending on which group has the highest total

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/ >
        <title>Smoothed D3.js Radar Chart</title>

        <!-- Google fonts -->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <!-- D3.js -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: "AkkuratPro", fallback, sans-serif;
                font-size: 11px;
                font-weight: 500;
                fill: #242424;

                cursor: default;
            }
            
            .legend {
                font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
                fill: #333333;
            }
            
            .tooltip {
                fill: #333333;
            }
      @font-face {
        font-family: "AkkuratPro";
        src: url(AkkuratPro.ttf) format("truetype");
      }
      * {
        background: #e3e0d7;
        border: 1px solid;
      }
      span {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
      }
      

      #questionContainer {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }
      .question-line {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center; /* Zentriert die Elemente vertikal */
        justify-content: space-between; /* Verteilt die Elemente gleichmäßig im Container */
      }
      .question {
        display: none;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }

      .question label {
        display: none;
      }
      .question span {
        margin-left: 50px;
        margin-right: 50px;
      }
      input[type="radio"] {
        -moz-appearance: None;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        border: Solid 10px #d7d5cc;
        width: 20px; /* Setzt die Breite des Radio-Buttons */
        height: 20px; /* Setzt die Höhe des Radio-Buttons */
      }

      input[type="radio"]:checked {
        border: solid 10px black;
      }

      input[type="radio"][value="0"] {
        background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        border: none;
        width: 1.5px; /* Setzt die Breite des Radio-Buttons mit dem Wert 0 */
        height: 40px; /* Setzt die Höhe des Radio-Buttons mit dem Wert 0 */
        margin-top: -8px;
      }
      #submitBtn {
        border: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 14px;
      }
      #counter {
        color: #a3a3a3;
      }
      #result {
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        align-items: center;
      }
      #resultTitle {
        background: black;
        color: white;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
        width: fit-content;
      }
      .radarChart{
        padding: 20px;
        overflow: visible;
      }
      
      #download {
        border: none;
      }
        </style>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Brandbarometer</h1>

    <form id="questionForm">
      <div id="questionContainer"></div>
      <button type="submit" disabled id="submitBtn">
        NÄCHSTE FRAGE &rarr;
      </button>
      <div id="counter">1 / 24</div>
      <div id="result" style="display: none">
            <div class="radarChart"></div>
        
        <div id="resultWrapper">
          <h2 id="resultTitle"></h2>
          <p id="resultText"></p>
        </div>
        <button id="download">
          Dein Ergebnis<i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-down"></i></i>
        </button>
      </div>

            
        <script>
      var questions = [
        { key: 0, question1: "aussergewoehnlich", question2: "normal" },
        { key: 1, question1: "schnell", question2: "gruendlich" },
        { key: 2, question1: "experimentell", question2: "routiniert" },
        { key: 3, question1: "impulsiv", question2: "ueberlegt" },
        { key: 4, question1: "spontan", question2: "geplant" },
        { key: 5, question1: "mutig", question2: "zurueckhaltend" },
        { key: 6, question1: "laut", question2: "leise" },
        { key: 7, question1: "dynamisch", question2: "statisch" },
        { key: 8, question1: "hart", question2: "kooperativ" },
        { key: 9, question1: "fordernd", question2: "gebend" },
        { key: 10, question1: "solitaer", question2: "kollektiv" },
        { key: 11, question1: "elitaer", question2: "empathisch" },
        { key: 12, question1: "durchsetzungsstark", question2: "angepasst" },
        { key: 13, question1: "steil", question2: "flach" },
        { key: 14, question1: "herausfordernd", question2: "gemuetlich" },
        { key: 15, question1: "diszipliniert", question2: "locker" },
        { key: 16, question1: "strukturiert", question2: "phantasievoll" },
        { key: 17, question1: "nuechtern", question2: "leidenschaftlich" },
        { key: 18, question1: "spezialisiert", question2: "vielseitig" },
        { key: 19, question1: "kontrolliert", question2: "intuitiv" },
        { key: 20, question1: "geizig", question2: "grosszuegig" },
        { key: 21, question1: "aufopfernd", question2: "hedonistisch" },
        { key: 22, question1: "traditionell", question2: "exotisch" },
        { key: 23, question1: "pflichtbewusst", question2: "neugierig" },
      ];

      var groupColors = [
        "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.7)",
        "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.7)",
        "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.7)",
        "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.7)",
        "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.7)",
        "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.7)",
      ];

      
      var radarChartOptions;

      function checkSubmitButtonState(questionElement) {
        var answer = questionElement.querySelector(
          "input[type='radio']:checked"
        ).value;
        submitBtn.disabled = answer === 0;
      }

      // Mischen der Fragen
      questions.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

      var questionContainer = document.getElementById("questionContainer");
      var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
      // Add checkValue function
      function checkValue(index) {
        var selectedRadioButton = document.querySelector(
          `input[name="answer${index + 1}"]:checked`
        );
        var value = selectedRadioButton.value;
        if (value == 0) {
          submitBtn.disabled = true;
        } else {
          submitBtn.disabled = false;
        }
      }

      questions.forEach(function (q, index) {
        var questionDiv = document.createElement("div");
        questionDiv.className = "question";
        questionDiv.dataset.key = q.key;
        questionDiv.innerHTML = `
<div class="question-line">
  <span>${q.question1}</span>
  <div class="radio-container">
`;

        for (let i = -10; i <= 10; i++) {
          questionDiv.innerHTML += `
    <input type="radio" name="answer${index + 1}" id="answer${
            index + 1
          }-${i}" value="${i}" ${
            i === 0 ? "checked" : ""
          } oninput="checkValue(${index})">
    <label for="answer${index + 1}-${i}">${i}</label>
  `;
        }

        questionDiv.innerHTML += `
  </div>
  <span>${q.question2}</span>
</div>
`;
        questionContainer.appendChild(questionDiv);
        checkValue(index);
      });

      // Benachbarte Radio-Buttons einfärben

      document
        .querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')
        .forEach((radio, index, array) => {
          radio.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
            // Setze alle Radio-Buttons auf die ursprüngliche Farbe zurück
            array.forEach((el) => (el.style.borderColor = "#d7d5cc"));

            // Setze die Farbe des ausgewählten Radio-Buttons
            event.target.style.borderColor = "black";

            // Setze die Farben der benachbarten Radio-Buttons
            if (index > 0)
              // Prüfe, ob es ein linkes Nachbarelement gibt
              array[index - 1].style.borderColor = "#a3a3a3"; // Farbe für linken Nachbarn

            if (index < array.length - 1)
              // Prüfe, ob es ein rechtes Nachbarelement gibt
              array[index + 1].style.borderColor = "#a3a3a3"; // Farbe für rechten Nachbarn
          });
        });

      var currentQuestionIndex = 0;
      var questionElements = document.getElementsByClassName("question");
      questionElements[currentQuestionIndex].style.display = "flex";

      var form = document.getElementById("questionForm");
      form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var answers = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < questionElements.length; i++) {
          var questionElement = questionElements[i];
          var key = questionElement.dataset.key; // Abrufen des Schlüssels
          var answer = document.querySelector(
            `input[name="answer${i + 1}"]:checked`
          ).value;
          answers[key] = answer; // Speichern der Antwort an der entsprechenden Position im Array
        }

        console.log(answers);

        questionElements[currentQuestionIndex].style.display = "none";
        currentQuestionIndex++;
        if (currentQuestionIndex < questionElements.length) {
          questionElements[currentQuestionIndex].style.display = "flex";
          // Überprüfen des Zustands des 'Submit'-Buttons
          checkSubmitButtonState(questionElements[currentQuestionIndex]);
        } else {
          var finalvalues = [];
          for (i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            if (answers[i] > 0) {
              finalvalues[i] = 0;
              finalvalues[i + 24] = answers[i];
            } else {
              finalvalues[i] = Math.abs(answers[i]);
              finalvalues[i + 24] = 0;
            }
          }
          console.log(finalvalues);
          for (let i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
    data[0][i].value = finalvalues[i];
}
          console.log(data);
          RadarChart(".radarChart", data, radarChartOptions);

          var groups = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < finalvalues.length; i += 8) {
          groups.push(finalvalues.slice(i, i + 8));
        }

        // Summe jeder Gruppe berechnen
        var groupSums = groups.map(function (group) {
          return group.reduce(function (sum, value) {
            return sum + Number(value);
          }, 0);
        });

        // Gruppe mit der höchsten Summe ermitteln
        var maxSumIndex = groupSums.reduce(
          (iMax, x, i, arr) => (x > arr[iMax] ? i : iMax),
          0
        );

        // Die Farbe auf Basis des Indexes der Gruppe mit der höchsten Summe setzen
        
        var color = groupColors[maxSumIndex % groupColors.length];
        console.log(color);
        console.log(maxSumIndex);
        radarChartOptions = {
              w: width,
              h: height,
              margin: margin,
              maxValue: .5,
              levels: 10,
              roundStrokes: true,
              color: color
            };

        var groupLabels = [
          " Abwechslung ",
          " Bedeutung ",
          " Beitrag Leisten ",
          " Sicherheit/Komfort ",
          " Zugehörigkeit ",
          " Wachstum ",
        ];

        var groupTexts = [
          "Sie suchen nach Abwechslung und neuen Erfahrungen in Ihrer Arbeit.",
          "Sie legen großen Wert auf die Bedeutung und den Zweck Ihrer Arbeit.",
          "Sie möchten einen signifikanten Beitrag leisten und einen positiven Einfluss haben.",
          "Sie schätzen Sicherheit und Komfort in Ihrem Arbeitsumfeld.",
          "Sie suchen nach einem Gefühl der Zugehörigkeit und Gemeinschaft am Arbeitsplatz.",
          "Sie streben nach persönlichem Wachstum und Entwicklung in Ihrer Karriere.",
        ];

        var maxGroup = groupLabels[maxSumIndex];
        var maxGroupText = groupTexts[maxSumIndex];

        // Setzen Sie die Überschrift und den Text basierend auf der Gruppe mit der höchsten Summe
        document.getElementById("resultTitle").innerText = maxGroup;
        document.getElementById("resultText").innerText = maxGroupText;

        document.getElementById("result").style.display = "flex";
        document.getElementById("submitBtn").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("counter").style.display = "none";

        }
        // Aktualisieren des Zählers
        var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
        counter.textContent = currentQuestionIndex + 1 + " / 24";
      });
      /* Radar chart design created by Nadieh Bremer - VisualCinnamon.com */
      

      

            var margin = {top: 100, right: 100, bottom: 100, left: 100},
                width = Math.min(700, window.innerWidth - 10) - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = Math.min(width, window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom - 20);
                    


            var data = [
                      [//iPhone
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"Abwechslung",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"Bedeutung",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0.0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"Beitrag Leisten",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"Sicherheit / Komfort",value:0.},
                        {axis:"",value:0.},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"Zugehörigkeit",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"Wachstum",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0},
                        {axis:"",value:0}                                   
                      ]
                    ];
        

          function RadarChart(id, data, options) {
  var cfg = {
    w: 300, //Width of the circle
    h: 300, //Height of the circle
    margin: { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20 }, //The margins of the SVG
    levels: 3, //How many levels or inner circles should there be drawn
    maxValue: 10, //What is the value that the biggest circle will represent
    labelFactor: 1.1, //How much farther than the radius of the outer circle should the labels be placed
    opacityArea: 1, //The opacity of the area of the blob
    dotRadius: 0, //The size of the colored circles of each blog
    opacityCircles: 0.1, //The opacity of the circles of each blob
    strokeWidth: 2, //The width of the stroke around each blob
    roundStrokes: false, //If true the area and stroke will follow a round path (cardinal-closed)
    color: d3.scale.category10(), //Color function
  };

  //Put all of the options into a variable called cfg
  if ("undefined" !== typeof options) {
    for (var i in options) {
      if ("undefined" !== typeof options[i]) {
        cfg[i] = options[i];
      }
    } //for i
  } //if

  //If the supplied maxValue is smaller than the actual one, replace by the max in the data
  var maxValue = Math.max(
    cfg.maxValue,
    d3.max(data, function (i) {
      return d3.max(
        i.map(function (o) {
          return o.value;
        })
      );
    })
  );

  var allAxis = data[0].map(function (i, j) {
      return i.axis;
    }), //Names of each axis
    total = allAxis.length, //The number of different axes
    radius = Math.min(cfg.w / 2, cfg.h / 2), //Radius of the outermost circle
    Format = d3.format("%"), //Percentage formatting
    angleSlice = (Math.PI * 2) / total; //The width in radians of each "slice"

  //Scale for the radius
  var rScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, radius]).domain([0, maxValue]);

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //////////// Create the container SVG and g /////////////
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  //Remove whatever chart with the same id/class was present before
  d3.select(id).select("svg").remove();

  //Initiate the radar chart SVG
  var svg = d3
    .select(id)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", cfg.w + cfg.margin.left + cfg.margin.right)
    .attr("height", cfg.h + cfg.margin.top + cfg.margin.bottom)
    .attr("class", "radar" + id);
  //Append a g element
  var g = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr(
      "transform",
      "translate(" +
        (cfg.w / 2 + cfg.margin.left) +
        "," +
        (cfg.h / 2 + cfg.margin.top) +
        ")"
    );

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ////////// Glow filter for some extra pizzazz ///////////
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  //Filter for the outside glow
  var filter = g.append("defs").append("filter").attr("id", "glow"),
    feGaussianBlur = filter
      .append("feGaussianBlur")
      .attr("stdDeviation", "2.5")
      .attr("result", "coloredBlur"),
    feMerge = filter.append("feMerge"),
    feMergeNode_1 = feMerge.append("feMergeNode").attr("in", "coloredBlur"),
    feMergeNode_2 = feMerge.append("feMergeNode").attr("in", "SourceGraphic");

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  /////////////// Draw the Circular grid //////////////////
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  //Wrapper for the grid & axes
  var axisGrid = g.append("g").attr("class", "axisWrapper");

  //Draw the background circles
  axisGrid
    .selectAll(".levels")
    .data(d3.range(1, cfg.levels + 1).reverse())
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "gridCircle")
    .attr("r", function (d, i) {
      return (radius / cfg.levels) * d;
    })
    .style("fill", "#CDCDCD")
    .style("stroke", "#CDCDCD")
    .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityCircles)
    .style("filter", "url(#glow)");

  //Text indicating at what % each level is
  axisGrid
    .selectAll(".axisLabel")
    .data(d3.range(1, cfg.levels + 1).reverse())
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "axisLabel")
    .attr("x", 4)
    .attr("y", function (d) {
      return (-d * radius) / cfg.levels;
    })
    .attr("dy", "0.4em")
    .style("font-size", "10px")
    .attr("fill", "#737373")
    .text(function (d, i) {
      return Format((maxValue * d) / cfg.levels);
    });

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //////////////////// Draw the axes //////////////////////
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  //Create the straight lines radiating outward from the center
  var axis = axisGrid
    .selectAll(".axis")
    .data(allAxis)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis");

  // Append the lines
  axis
    .append("line")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", function (d, i) {
      return rScale(maxValue * 1.1) * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
    })
    .attr("y2", function (d, i) {
      return rScale(maxValue * 1.1) * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
    })
    .attr("class", "line")
    .style("stroke", "transparent")
    .style("stroke-width", "2px");

  // Append the labels at each axis
  axis
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .style("font-size", "20px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dy", "0.35em")
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
      return (
        rScale(maxValue * cfg.labelFactor) *
        Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2)
      );
    })
    .attr("y", function (d, i) {
      return (
        rScale(maxValue * cfg.labelFactor) *
        Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2)
      );
    })
    .text(function (d) {
      return d;
    })
    .call(wrap, cfg.wrapWidth)
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
      var angle = (angleSlice * i * 180) / Math.PI;
      var x =
        rScale(maxValue * cfg.labelFactor) *
        Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
      var y =
        rScale(maxValue * cfg.labelFactor) *
        Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
      return `translate(${x},${y}) rotate(${angle}) translate(${-x},${-y})`;
    });

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ///////////// Draw the radar chart blobs ////////////////
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  //The radial line function
  var radarLine = d3.svg.line
    .radial()
    .interpolate("linear-closed")
    .radius(function (d) {
      return rScale(d.value);
    })
    .angle(function (d, i) {
      return i * angleSlice;
    });

  if (cfg.roundStrokes) {
    radarLine.interpolate("cardinal-closed");
  }

  //Create a wrapper for the blobs
  var blobWrapper = g
    .selectAll(".radarWrapper")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "radarWrapper");

  //Append the backgrounds
  blobWrapper
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "radarArea")
    .attr("d", function (d, i) {
      return radarLine(d);
    })
    .style("fill", function (d, i) {
      return cfg.color(i);
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea)
    .on("mouseover", function (d, i) {
      //Dim all blobs
      d3.selectAll(".radarArea")
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("fill-opacity", 0.1);
      //Bring back the hovered over blob
      d3.select(this).transition().duration(200).style("fill-opacity", 0.7);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function () {
      //Bring back all blobs
      d3.selectAll(".radarArea")
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea);
    });

  //Create the outlines
  blobWrapper
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "radarStroke")
    .attr("d", function (d, i) {
      return radarLine(d);
    })
    .style("stroke-width", cfg.strokeWidth + "px")
    .style("stroke", function (d, i) {
      return cfg.color(i);
    })
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("filter", "url(#glow)");

  //Append the circles
  blobWrapper
    .selectAll(".radarCircle")
    .data(function (d, i) {
      return d;
    })
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "radarCircle")
    .attr("r", cfg.dotRadius)
    .attr("cx", function (d, i) {
      return rScale(d.value) * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
    })
    .attr("cy", function (d, i) {
      return rScale(d.value) * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
    })
    .style("fill", function (d, i, j) {
      return cfg.color(j);
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 0.8);

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //////// Append invisible circles for tooltip ///////////
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  //Wrapper for the invisible circles on top
  var blobCircleWrapper = g
    .selectAll(".radarCircleWrapper")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "radarCircleWrapper");

  //Append a set of invisible circles on top for the mouseover pop-up
  blobCircleWrapper
    .selectAll(".radarInvisibleCircle")
    .data(function (d, i) {
      return d;
    })
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "radarInvisibleCircle")
    .attr("r", cfg.dotRadius * 1.5)
    .attr("cx", function (d, i) {
      return rScale(d.value) * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
    })
    .attr("cy", function (d, i) {
      return rScale(d.value) * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
    })
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("pointer-events", "all")
    .on("mouseover", function (d, i) {
      newX = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("cx")) - 10;
      newY = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("cy")) - 10;

      tooltip
        .attr("x", newX)
        .attr("y", newY)
        .text(Format(d.value))
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", 1);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function () {
      tooltip.transition().duration(200).style("opacity", 0);
    });

  //Set up the small tooltip for when you hover over a circle
  var tooltip = g.append("text").attr("class", "tooltip").style("opacity", 0);

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  /////////////////// Helper Function /////////////////////
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  //Taken from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321
  //Wraps SVG text
  function wrap(text, width) {
    text.each(function () {
      var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.4, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        x = text.attr("x"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text
          .text(null)
          .append("tspan")
          .attr("x", x)
          .attr("y", y)
          .attr("dy", dy + "em");

      while ((word = words.pop())) {
        line.push(word);
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
          line.pop();
          tspan.text(line.join(" "));
          line = [word];
          tspan = text
            .append("tspan")
            .attr("x", x)
            .attr("y", y)
            .attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em")
            .text(word);
        }
      }
    });
  } //wrap
} //RadarChart
    
                
            
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```